# How to embed my photos to another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed

I have a Spring MVC CRUD app for storing images. My app stores the files on the server and puts their addresses into database, so I can access them. I need to create a gallery from selected images and generate an embed/iframe code to embed this gallery to another site.

I can create a gallery, for example, with Colorbox or write it by myself, but how should I generate the embed code?

I've read a lot stuff about this, but didn't find the appropriate answer. I'm new to JavaScript so I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for this purpose is a dynamic page (ASP or PHP or other dynamic languages) which generates HTML but using Javascript `document.write`  to present the output as a javascript file:

This is a sample code by ASP:

File: **code.asp**

```
<%
sql="select * from photos order by id desc"
recordset.open sql,objconnection
while not recordset.eof
%>
document.write ('<img src="http://www.example.com/<%=recordset("id")%>.jpg" style="border:0"><br><%=rs("title")%>');
<%
recordset.movenext
wend
recordset.close
%>
```

As the output of this file is in standard format of JavaScript,So you can link to it from a `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/code.asp"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I don't know ASP language, could you please give me some more advices? I will access the photos for the code not from database directly, but from a list (ArrayList) which will contain file addresses. How can I do it here? And where should I put some jQuery stuff for moving images?